# Replace pattern in one column bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have multiple *csv file that cat like:

```
#sample,time,N
SPH-01-HG00186-1_R1_001,8.33386,93
SPH-01-HG00266-1_R1_001,7.41229,93
SPH-01-HG00274-1_R1_001,7.63903,93
SPH-01-HG00276-1_R1_001,7.94798,93
SPH-01-HG00403-1_R1_001,7.99299,93
SPH-01-HG00404-1_R1_001,8.38001,93
```

And I try to wrangle cated csv file to:

```
#sample,time,N
HG00186,8.33386,93
HG00266,7.41229,93
HG00274,7.63903,93
HG00276,7.94798,93
HG00403,7.99299,93
HG00404,8.38001,93
```

I did:

```
for i in $(ls *csv); do line=$(cat ${i} | grep -v "#" | cut -d'-' -f3); sed 's/*${line}*/${line}/g'; done
```

Yet no result showed up... Any advice of doing so? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself ?

Comment: This is most probably a job for `awk` or `sed`

Comment: also, what's the logic for converting `SPH-01-HG00186-1_R1_001` to `HG00186`? The third dash delimited field? The word that starts with `H`?

Comment: conversion is only use match for later use, I would like to replace the entire string in column 1 with its own third dash delimited field, and it could be started with any character.

Comment: It is not correct to use a `*` at the start of the regex, it matches nothing there in a POSIX regex, and is an error in NFA regex flavors. To match any text, you need `.*`, but this won't work in your case. I added an answer with pattern explanation so that you could learn a bit more about POSIX regex.

Comment: Please run your shell script through http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Answer (score 4):

With `awk` and the logic of splitting each line by `,` then split their first field by `-`:

```bash
awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' 'NR > 1 { split($1,w,"-"); $1 = w[3] } 1' file.csv
```

With `sed` and a robust regex that cannot possibly modify the other fields:

```bash
sed -E 's/^([^,-]*-){2}([^,-]*)[^,]*/\2/' file.csv
# or
sed -E 's/^(([^,-]*)-){3}[^,]*/\2/' file.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i -pe 's{.*?-.*?-(.*?)-.*?,}{$1,}' *.csv
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak` (you can omit `.bak`, to avoid creating any backup files).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```bash
sed -E 's/^[^-]+-[0-9]+-([^-]+)[^,]+/\1/' file > newfile
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - enabling the POSIX ERE regex flavor
- `^[^-]+-[0-9]+-([^-]+)[^,]+` - the regex pattern that searches for

  - `^`  - start of string
  - `[^-]+` - one or more non-hyphen chars
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `([^-]+)` - Group 1: one or more non-hyphens
  - `[^,]+` - one or more non-comma chars
- `\1` - replace the match with Group 1 value.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/t2ZCh6):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='SPH-01-HG00186-1_R1_001,8.33386,93
SPH-01-HG00266-1_R1_001,7.41229,93
SPH-01-HG00274-1_R1_001,7.63903,93
SPH-01-HG00276-1_R1_001,7.94798,93
SPH-01-HG00403-1_R1_001,7.99299,93
SPH-01-HG00404-1_R1_001,8.38001,93'
sed -E 's/^[^-]+-[0-9]+-([^-]+)[^,]+/\1/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
HG00186,8.33386,93
HG00266,7.41229,93
HG00274,7.63903,93
HG00276,7.94798,93
HG00403,7.99299,93
HG00404,8.38001,93
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mangle text using bash parameter expansion, without resorting to external tools like awk and sed:

```
IFS=","
while read -r -a line; do
  x="${line[0]%-*}"
  x="${x##*-}"
  printf "%s,%s,%s\n" "$x" "${line[1]}" "${line[2]}"
done < input.txt
```

Or you could do it with simple awk, as others have done.

```
awk '{print $3,$5,$6}' FS='[-,]' OFS=, < input.txt
```

Comment: Regarding `without resorting to external tools like awk and sed` - that's like saying you could walk 20 miles to work every day instead of resorting to external tools like cars and buses. The guys who invented shell also invented sed and awk for shell to call to manipulate text. As you show, an awk script is much simpler but it's also more portable and far more efficient than a shell loop. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: I created an input file like the OPs that had 500,000 entries in it - your shell script took just over 2 minutes to process it while your awk script took just under 2 seconds (even after fixing the bug in not handling the first line correctly - `'NR>1{print $3,$5,$6; next} 1'`).

Comment: No-one who asks about doing something "in bash" is ever really asking how to do a thing using bash bultins, they're always asking how to do it using a bash script and that includes using available tools. The problem with your answer is that `without resorting to external tools like awk and sed` makes it sound to a newcomer like there's some reason to avoid such tools and that doing it using bash builtins has a benefit in some way when in fact neither thing is true. If you want to post scripts like that then you should warn people of the negatives rather than making it sound positive.

Comment: As for "the same people" - sure it was, they all sat in the same couple of aisles at Bell Labs, I met some of them there to discuss design validation and code generation tools in the early 90s when we were all working for the same company. Sorry you're taking my comment personally.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `cut` AT ANY PRICE then I suggest following solution, let `file.txt` content be

```
#sample,time,N
SPH-01-HG00186-1_R1_001,8.33386,93
SPH-01-HG00266-1_R1_001,7.41229,93
SPH-01-HG00274-1_R1_001,7.63903,93
SPH-01-HG00276-1_R1_001,7.94798,93
SPH-01-HG00403-1_R1_001,7.99299,93
SPH-01-HG00404-1_R1_001,8.38001,93
```

then

```
head -1 file.txt && tail -6 file.txt | tr '-' ',' | cut --delimiter=',' --fields=3,5,6
```

gives output

```
#sample,time,N
HG00186,8.33386,93
HG00266,7.41229,93
HG00274,7.63903,93
HG00276,7.94798,93
HG00403,7.99299,93
HG00404,8.38001,93
```

Explanation: output 1st line as-is using `head` then ram 6 last lines into `tr` to replace `-` using `,` finally use `cut` with `,` delimiter and specify desired fields.

Answer (score -1):

```
{m,n,g}awk NF++ FS='^[^-]+-[^-]+-|-[^,]+' OFS=
```

|

```
#sample,time,N
HG00186,8.33386,93
HG00266,7.41229,93
HG00274,7.63903,93
HG00276,7.94798,93
HG00403,7.99299,93
HG00404,8.38001,93
```